# ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\StaticPagesController@faq does not exist Laravel-5

Tags: php, github, laravel-5

I cloned this [todstoychev/Laravel5Starter](https://github.com/todstoychev/Laravel5Starter) from Github and installed it.

After creating this `StaticPagesController` controller and updating my routes.php file. The controller does not seem to work. For some reason i keep getting the following error.

```
ReflectionException in ControllerInspector.php line 32:
Class App\Http\Controllers\StaticPagesController@faq does not exist
```

**My routes.php file**

```
<?php

// Admin routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {
    Route::controller('permissions', 'AdminPermissionsController');

    Route::controller('settings', 'AdminSettingsController');

    Route::controller('roles', 'AdminRolesController');

    Route::controller('users', 'AdminUsersController');

    Route::controller('/', 'AdminController');
});

// Public and user routes
Route::controller('contacts', 'ContactsController');

Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');

Route::controller('/', 'IndexController');

Route::controller('faq', 'StaticPagesController@faq');
```

**My StaticPagesController.php file**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class StaticPagesController extends Controller
{
    public function faq(){
        return 'this is faq page';
    }
}
```

I have tried `composer update`, `php artisan acl:update`, `composer dumpautoload` to no avail.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line:

```
Route::controller('faq', 'StaticPagesController@faq');
```

You are telling Laravel that the controller for `faq` shoule be `StaticPagesController@faq`. The `Route::controller` method sets an entire controller for a route, it does not specify a method to be used on that route, Laravel handles this internally. Take a look at your error to prove my point:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\StaticPagesController@faq does not exist
```

It is looking for class `StaticPagesController@faq` not `StaticPagesController` as you are intending.

Unless you are building an API using REST, you should not use the `controller` method and instead specify your routes explicitly, i.e.

```
Route::get('faq', 'StaticPagesController@faq');
```

This will use the `faq` method on your controller when the user makes a GET request to the URI `faq`. If you insist on using the `controller` method, then remove the `@faq` from the second argument and you will be good, although I'm pretty sure Laravel expects the methods **index, show, create, etc** to be in your controller. I suggest taking a look at the [Laravel 5 Fundamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals) video course to help you get a better understanding.